# Getting invalid parameter response when creating geo_locations targeting spec in the Facebook Marketing api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to add cities to my geo_location targeting in a facebook marketing api call.

```
$targeting_spec = array(
            'geo_locations' => [
                'countries' => ['US'],
                'cities' =>
                    ['key' => '2490299','radius' => 10, 'distance_unit' => 'mile']
            ],

            'age_min' => 13,

        );
```

My code above seems like it should be correct, especially after looking at the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting/tutorial). However I get the following error:

> {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"error_subcode":1487079,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"Invalid Targeting Spec","error_user_msg":"The specified targeting spec is not valid because: Invalid data for field geo_locations. Invalid Targeting Spec: The specified targeting spec is not valid because: Normalization expecs a KeyedTraversable. TAAL[BLAME_file]\n","fbtrace_id":"HwU9EMDTah1"}}

It seems to be saying there's something invalid about my geo_locations field but I have no idea what that could be.  Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For any lost souls who end up here I figured out what was wrong.  The correct targeting is below:

```
$targeting_spec = array(
            'geo_locations' => [
                'cities' =>
                    array(['key' => '2490299','radius' => 10, 'distance_unit' => 'mile'])
            ],

            'age_min' => 13,

        );
```

Comment: this is so dumb.  Facebook for as big as it is needs better documentations or just take away their damn API, one or the other.  I'm working on a project that is 100% directed around the API and it's been the biggest pain in my life.  Not to mention there is no guarantee that when I am finished facebook will even approve the app.